# Is it possible to insert records if not exists and delete records if not provided in Laravel and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

I have couple of checkboxes in my Laravel View lets say:

```
<input type="check" name="John">
<input type="check" name="Jane">
<input type="check" name="Mae">
<input type="check" name="Peter">
```

When I check all of the checkboxes, It will be save in the database like so:

```
#Participants Table
_____________
id  |  name
----+--------
 1  |  John
 2  |  jane
 3  |  Mae
 4  |  Peter
```

In my Log table:

```
#Log Table
_________________
id  |  activity
----+------------
 1  |  Added John as participant
 2  |  Added jane as participant
 3  |  Added Mae as participant
 4  |  Added Peter as participant
```

Now, my problem is when updating the `participants`.; In my Laravel view, I have all my checkbox selected based on the participants table data and let's say I unchecked `John` and `Peter`, When click update How can I add a history in my Log table that will display like this:

```
#Log Table
_________________
id  |  activity
----+------------
 1  |  Added John as participant
 2  |  Added jane as participant
 3  |  Added Mae as participant
 4  |  Added Peter as participant
 5  |  Removed John as participant
 6  |  Removed Peter as participant
```

and then in my Participants Table

```
#Participants Table
_____________
id  |  name
----+--------
 2  |  jane
 3  |  Mae
```

What I have done so far on Update:

```
$members = json_decode($request->projectmembers);
foreach ($members as $participantsitems) {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    DB::table('projects_participants')->upsert([
        'project_id' => $request->projectid,
        'task_id' => "",
        'emp_number' => $participantsitems->id,
        'created_by' => Auth::user()->emp_number,
        'date_created' => Carbon::parse(Carbon::now()),
    ],
    [
        'project_id' => $request->projectid, 
        'emp_number' => $participantsitems->id,
    ]);
    DB::commit();
    $this->record_project_history("Added ".$participantsitems->name ." as participant",$request->projectid, "");
}
```

But what it did was insert if record does not exists and update if record exists. can anyone give me an Idea on how to solve my problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct why to do that.
you should do this logic yourself.

But you there're some staff could help you (append to you method this snippet):

```
// after update/insert your new data you will need to delete other records
// using updated_at column to delete all records updated a second ago
// make sure to create a model for projects_participants and use it all over your code
ProjectsParticipant::where('project_id', $request->projectid)
->where('updated_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subSecond())->delete();
```